# How Can I Access an Alias Value in Controller?

Tags: symfony

I have created a query in my repository which returns the sum of marks and i have given it an alias. below is the code:-

```
public function findAllResults()
    {
        $query = $this->getEntityManager()
                ->createQuery("
                SELECT res, sum(res.marks) as total 
                FROM CollegeStudentBundle:Results res, CollegeStudentBundle:Student std
                WHERE std.id = res.student_id group by std.firstname");
        return $query->execute();
    }
```

if i would like to check any field from res I write code as :-

```
echo "<pre>"; print_r($results[0][0]->getStudentId()->getfirstname()); exit;
```

Now my problem is I want to print the total as well when i tried this code :-

```
echo "<pre>"; print_r($results[0][0]->getTotal()); exit;
```

it gives me error. How Can I access that value. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a `var_dump` on the `$result`. I think `total` field is outside of the found entities object. So `$result[0]['total']` may work.

Comment: Thanks For The Answer, I got a Clue for it. Actually I can access it with $result['total']